# Python REST POST Handling Large Requests

Tags: docker, rest, google-kubernetes-engine, api-design, restful-authentication

I'm working on a machine learning application in python that will be contained in a docker on a kubernetes cluster. In this implementation I'll be using Google Cloud Platform.

A user will access the endpoint with a post command sending in the data they want to test against the model. The data could come in as 10k requests with one row of data per request or it could come in as one block of 10k rows. The api should be able to handle it either way with a small difference in performance.

For the 10k requests sent row by row the built in load balancing and spinning up more instances of the docker will take care of the workload just fine.

I'm not sure how to handle the request that sends 10k rows at once. Is there some way to easily share one large request with other instances of the docker and then combine the result to send back to the user?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. If you're asking "how can I distribute data and a computational task across many nodes", there are lots of solutions for that out there. Whether they're appropriate or not depends very much on the nature of what you're doing. Typical solutions may involve message passing, work queues, databases, etc.

Comment: @larsks I know you can distribute incoming requests with a load balancer and having different messages routed to different nodes. I'm not sure how to distribute the tasks across many nodes if it comes in as one request. For this there is no database I can setup or use.

Comment: Typically, you would set up a message queue, subscribe all your workers to it, then put tasks on the queue where they will be consumed by your workers.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can handle in the same way 10k requests or 1 heavy request. I mean how do you plan to split this request and joining back together? Without more details my only option would be to to get a SSD PD or balanced PD on your cluster to catch those heavy requests.

Other way it's to depending your deployment having another external api that can split up the requests of the users before sending.